# General EDI XML processing from different parties

Tags: sql, xml, edi

We're starting with EDI with one of our suppliers. We agreed on a fairly simple XML structure that contains all necessary info to place an order, but no more than that.

I will write a tool to generate these XML purchase order files based on the ERP data in our SQL Server database (the ERP can't generate the XML's), and to import the order confirmation and shipment messages that will come from the supplier.

I would like to make things as general as possible, so other xml file formats from other suppliers can be processed too by only adding some configuration. So no hardcoded parsing per supplier.

I'm not an expert on these matters, but I was thinking along the lines of some kind of mapping table in SQL Server that contains the data fields we need (order number, requested date, ordered quantity,...), and then per supplier file format the path in the XML file structure where this element can be found.

So for example we're looking for the order number. For supplier A the order number can be found here:

```
<ediroot><message><head><ordernumber>
```

For supplier B the order number can be found here:

```
<ediroot><message><header><body><order_number>
```

This way I only have to add lines to this mapping table to be able to support new XML file types.

Or does this all seem too far fetched, and are there way easier/better solutions for this? We're an SME, we're not talking about millions of EDI messages to be processed.

Thanks

Comment: So you're planning on creating ORDERS from the DB and are going to go SQL -> XML -> Orders?  Why not SQL -> ORDERS?  Why use the intermediate file?  Seems like you're the only one introducing XML to this scenario.  In my environment, I'm mapping to/from SQL Server directly, complete with EDI dictionary management, trading partner management, CONTRL reconciliation using software for less than $20K.  You are reinventing the wheel and making life harder for yourself.  Especially if you're unfamiliar with the EDIFACT standard.

Comment: You *are aware* that there are EDI standards for most industries, and that your suppliers are probably going to be expecting your data to be compliant with those standards? It's typically not just a matter of "I'll dump some XML and send it to them".

Comment: @Andrew: I removed the reference to the EDI messages as we don't really need to deal with those directly. The supplier uses mapping software so we're free to suggest a file format. I chose XML as it's easy to deal with and fairly robust.

Comment: @Ken White: see other answer too. The supplier has mapping software and we agreed on an XML format. Forget the EDI standards for now.

Comment: That's terrific, until you have another supplier that doesn't, or wants a different format. The entire reason a standard was developed was so that people didn't have to reinvent the wheel over and over and over again, but that it was "as general as possible to allow reuse". Oh, well; not my time (or my company's money). :-)

Comment: The way this generally works is to have mapping software at both ends.  It keeps your employer more versatile, and keeps your supplier(s) happy.  These days, translation (mapping) software isn't limited to just EDI.  We're talking databases, XML, JSON, CSV, Excel, data file, web services.  It puts you in a position to solve any integration challenge, not just one put forth by a single supplier.

Comment: So...what are suggestions for mapping software? Altova's? Other recommendations?

Comment: I will offer up BOTS as an opensource EDI solution: http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/about_features.shtml.  I would also recommend Delta and ECS from Liaison (http://liaison.com/products/transform/delta) for a Windows based solution. So many products out there to choose from: mild to wild, and many different cost levels.